# Pre-Debug script in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I use Eclipse to code my project and in order to debug\run it I have a "Maven Build" configuration with a goal.

My question is: How can I run a script file that deletes my log files before the debug starts?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it automatically buy you can use a script or an ant file linked from your external tools menu. So before debugging you would need to run that external tool.

[image]

Maybe there is another way. You can delete it from a maven goal **if** you launch the app with maven. I don't know exactly how. You can launch with maven with the exec plugin. Codehouse site is down (terminated) so I link this tutorial:
http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2009/11/3-ways-to-run-java-main-from-maven/

**EDIT:**

You can delete the files using Apache Maven Clean Plugin:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/examples/delete_additional_files.html

You need to make both steps (delete logs and run with both plugins) execute when you build with the same goal and in the right order. I don't know how to do it but I am quite sure it is possible.

Comment: The external tool is a good option, but I'm looking to automate this task. I can't quite figure out how to do it with Maven....